# Two-Line CSS Menu Expanding Incorrectly

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu

I've got a two-line CSS-only menu that is expanding to three lines any time you click on one of the submenu options on the first line.  It's fine for the furthest left and further right options, but any of those in the middle completely screws it up and shifts everything else out of the way and down to another line.

Correct behavior:
[image]

Incorrect behavior:
[image]

Here is the CSS:

```
#cssmenu ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 7px 6px 0;
  background: #74c141 url(overlay.png) repeat-x 0 -110px;
  line-height: 100%;
  font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
#cssmenu li {
  margin: 0 5px;
  padding: 0 0 8px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
}
#cssmenu a,
#cssmenu a:link {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 13px;  
  color: #e7e5e5;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 8px 20px;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
}
#cssmenu a:hover {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
#cssmenu .active a,
#cssmenu li:hover > a {
  background: #90ce67 url(overlay.png) repeat-x 0 -40px;  
  color: #444;
  border-top: solid 1px  #f8f8f8;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover a,
#cssmenu li:hover li a {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  color: #666;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
}
#cssmenu ul ul a:hover {
  background: #74c141 url(overlay.png) repeat-x 0 -100px !important;
  color: #fff !important;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
}
#cssmenu li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  z-index: 1000;
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 250px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 0;
  background: #ffffff url(overlay.png) repeat-x 0 0;
  border: solid 1px #b4b4b4;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li {
  float: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 3px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul a,
#cssmenu ul ul a:link {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 12px;
}
#cssmenu ul:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}
* html #cssmenu ul {
  height: 1%;
}
```

I obviously want the menu elements to stay in place and not move when hovered over or clicked.  Thank you for looking!!!

Cheers,
Brian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it may be because the items in your list are changing width.

Remember that the following attributes adjust the total width of your elements:

- width
- padding
- margin
- border

attributes must be static. I for instance can see in the following selectors, that the border value changes from 1px, to 0px (due to the none value, in the second rule).

```
#cssmenu .active a,
#cssmenu li:hover > a {
  background: #90ce67 url(overlay.png) repeat-x 0 -40px;  
  color: #444;
  border-top: solid 1px  #f8f8f8;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover a,
#cssmenu li:hover li a {
  background: none;
  border: none; /* look at this maybe set it as 1px, with a transparent color value */
  color: #666;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
}
```

It would be helpful if you could post the html too.

Answer (score -1):

Brilliant, thanks jonhurlock!

I just removed the border-top from all elements, and it works perfectly.  I had gotten this code from a menu generator and didn't need that part at all.

I generally try to write as sparse of code as possible, removing every line I can and testing if stuff still works.  Hadn't done that on this menu!

Thanks again,
Brian

Comment: This ought to be a comment, not an answer.